# How to Target a file to another Product file in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have two **.m** files, both executed to a one product file. Does anyone know how to keep both files in one **Xcode** project and run the project without this error message in the screenshot?

[Folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPqrk.jpg)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdMzn.jpg)

Comment: Show the error message. Your screenshot shows nothing of importance.

Comment: @Eiko the error is not important...its because both code files are writing to the same product file, when build and run..screenshot just to clearify that..

Comment: It doesn't make sense what you say, sorry.

Comment: @Eiko no worry, i have edited the question and included a screenshot of the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include two files with a main method in the same target.

So exclude one of the files from your product (select the file, and in the inspector on the right side you can select the targets it belongs to).

If you want to build another product, select "New Target" and create a new one.